# How to explain Bereishis Rabbah 55:7 to a Noahide?

Tags: midrash

[There](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.55.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it is stated about the umos haoilom that Hashem will send them to gehinom and was asked by a Noahide why are they sent to gehinom.

Comment: actually, what is stated is one creative opinion about the hidden reference behind the use of the word "Moriah". One version I see quotes it as Akum, which would exclude Noachides. The Etz Yosef reads "מורה לעכו"ם לשון הוראה שיפסוק דינם או לשון יריה. שיורם ויורידם לגיהנם. וגירסת הילקוט שמשם מורה כחץ לעכו"ם"

Comment: @Elchanan, Perhaps you should quote the relevant parts here. By doing so, one should be able to clarify your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably  you are referring to

אָמַר רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן לֵוִי שֶׁמִּשָּׁם הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא מוֹרֶה לְאֻמּוֹת
הָעוֹלָם וּמוֹרִידָם לְגֵיהִנֹּם

*Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi said that from there (Har Homirah)  Hashem  instructs  the nations of the world and brings them down to Gehinnom*

That Medrash is almost saying the same thing as (L'Havdil)  "A court house is where the law is decided and people are taken to jail"

It would be self understood that "people are taken to jail" is not a reference to all people, only the guilty ones. Similarly the Medrash is only a reference to guilty members of the nations.

Why are they singled out?

Among other reasons it could be because  the Halacha is that in order for a non-Jew to receive a punishment he has to be conscious of the fact that he is doing something wrong.

The Midrash  starts by saying that Har HaMoriah is where Hashem teaches non-Jews. Therefore they understand right from wrong (possibly by the intuitive influence stemming from it) It therefore follows that if they do wrong they are taken to Gehinnom because of what is taught there. So it is their taking point to Gehinnom if guilty.

Yidden on the other hand  were taught on Har Sinai and through the giving of the Torah